# How to create Analyzer instance defined in schema.xml?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

I have a schema.xml like below.

```
<fieldType name="nametext" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.XXXAnalyzer"/>
</fieldType>
```

And, I would like to read this analyzer in the test method without hardcode like new XXXAnlayzer().

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Analyzer analyzer = getAnalyzer();
}
```

I appreciate if anyone help me to do this.

Comment: is it the custom analyzer or the analyzer provided by lucene?

Comment: if you dont want to hardcode the the analyzer name the check if you can use the spring framework for dependency management

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is custom analyzer which includes custom tokenizer and filter. Also, I can't use spring framework for now. And, the reason why I don't want to write hardcode is that tokenizer or token filter can be changed anytime and I don't want to change test code manually.

Comment: then why dont you use any factory design pattern here to create the instance of your class

Comment: Because we (our system) currently mange analyzers from the schema.xml file and I can't change it for now. This is why I ask like 'defined in schema.xml'.